# Irfanview shortcut not working initially

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, irfanview

Irfanview has a very useful (to me) random function mapped to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>.
I open an Irfanview session, open the miniatures tab, navigate to my folder of choice and double click on the image nearest to my mouse cursor to open it in the main window.

Then I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> and nothing happens.

- Clicking or doubleclicking on the image or outside of it does not work.
- Manually selecting the random menu works but does not unlock the shortcut.
- Reducing the viewer to icon and back does not fix the problem.
- Doing something else I still need to identify makes it work.

Why is it? Is it just IrfanView needing some time to load the whole folder (if so, why does the menu option work?) or is it something I can fix?